# How to check if Firestore client is offline and and change to online on Unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, offline

I am running Unity 2019.3.1. I have been trying to get a document from Firestoreusing the code below:

```
// docRef = database.Collection("Data").Document(documentName)
// database data type = FirebaseFirestore    
public IEnumerator GetSpecificUserDocumentAsync(DocumentReference docRef, string variable)
{
    Debug.Log(String.Format("Getting document {0} from database!", variable));
    yield return database.EnableNetworkAsync();
    Task<DocumentSnapshot> task = docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
    yield return new WaitForTaskCompletion(task);
    if (task.Result.Exists)
    {
        data[variable] = true;
        OnFireStoreResult.Invoke();
        Debug.Log(String.Format("Document data for {0} document:", task.Result.Id));
    }
    else
    {
        data[variable] = false;
        OnFireStoreResult.Invoke();
        Debug.Log(String.Format("Document does not exist!"));
    }
}

// WaitForTaskCompletion is within the same class as the above function
class WaitForTaskCompletion : CustomYieldInstruction
{
    Task task;

    // Create an enumerator that waits for the specified task to complete.
    public WaitForTaskCompletion(Task task)
    {
        instance.previousTask = task;
        instance.operationInProgress = true;
        this.task = task;
    }

    // Wait for the task to complete.
    public override bool keepWaiting
    {
        get
        {
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                instance.operationInProgress = false;
                instance.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                if (task.IsFaulted) Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

However, Unity will always show this error when I try to retrieve the document: `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.FirebaseException: Failed to get document because the client is offline.`
Is there a way to check if the client is offline and change it to online if so? Or is there a way to tell the client not to use the cache?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to check if the client is offline and change it to online if so?

No, the online state is managed by the SDK and not exposed by its API.

> Or is there a way to tell the client not to use the cache?

Unfortunately not.  With other platforms, you can use a [source option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options) to force either cache or server, but the documentation suggests this is not supported for Unity.